# how to select people in Office Automation programing with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

what i want realize is what i selected checkbox department,and the employee in this department will display in second div.so i can select the employee ,and display auto in selected employee div.i can transmit reviews to these selected people.it appears normally in Office Automation.But how can to solve this with javascript? my current code is :
 $sql = "select userName from hpc_empolyee ;";

Comment: Show what have did for this, I mean codes.

Comment: <div style="margin-left:10%;position:absolute;width:150px;overflow-y:scroll;">
 <table> 
       $sql = "select usename from hpc_user ;"; 
    echo '<table border=1px cellspacing=0 style="TABLE-LAYOUT:fixed" >';

       $sel=$conn->query($sql);

      while($row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
      {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td style="word-break:break-all;"><input type="checkbox" name="uId" value="'.$row[0].'" >'.$row[0].'</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
      }
   echo '</table>';
     ?>
</div>

Comment: function add_sub(el){
                if (el.checked)
                {
                    currNum += el.value;
                }
                else
                {
                    currNum -= el.value;
                }
               selected_user.value = currNum;
}

form.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
        add_sub(ev.target);
    }
},false);
   }

Comment: Please update you question, do not use comment  area for code structure. A proper question may only get support from users who watch it.

Comment: i select username directory.But so many users.I need to select department in first div, users will be dispalyed auto in seconde div,so how to do with javascript? thanks

Comment: Please update your code

Comment: @Sinto thanks.Do you have any ideas to choose users just like parent and child with javascrip ?

Comment: Are looking for something like https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp. please update your question

Comment: @Sinto，sorry ,i can't open w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp.my question is how to display  all people who in the same department in another div when a department is selected with checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My modify.php

```
if(isset($_POST['get_staff']))
{
  $staff=$_POST['get_staff'];
  $sql = "select distinct 中文名 from hpc_用户表 where 角色='$staff';"; 

  echo '<table  >';
  $sel=$conn->query($sql);
  while($row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
  {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td style="word-break:break-all;"><input type="checkbox" id="staff_input" value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="staff_div" class="staff" ></div>
<div class="selected_staff" id="selected_staff" onclick="this.focus();"></div><br />
```

My js:

```
function change_staff(id){
var data_to_fetch = $('#'+id).val();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"modify.php",
    dataType:'html',
    cache: false,    
    data: {get_staff: data_to_fetch},
    success: function(data){
        $('#staff_div').html("");
        $('#staff_div').html(data);

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

I wish alert("test") can work:

```
$('#staff_input').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     alert("test");     
    });     

 });
```